# Is it right to put data in html5 data-*?

Tags: javascript, html

I have got a case like this:

There are many 'Rocks' on the screen, each one has properties like gram, score and speed. Once click the rock, we give out its properties.

Now i put all rocks' properties on the dom with data-*, like data-gram, data-score and data-speed. 'e.target' is used to get the dom and so are all properties.

```
<div class="rocks" data-gram="10" data-score="100" data-speed="10"></div>
```

I want to know is it right, and is there any disadvantage?

Also,is there any other better way?

Comment: That's why it's there for, there are other solutions to, but this one certainly is valid. Note that you can access these properties trough jqueries `$.data` method.

Comment: @WillemD'Haeseleer - It's not difficult to do it with pure JS either: http://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/ and you can also use CSS to style stuff based on its data

Answer (score 1):

It is right, these `data-` fields are made for these kind of uses.

Another way to do it is simply creating an array or object in Javascript that holds that information. As you're accessing the DOM when you click the element, it simply won't matter.

If you were trying to access the data without a DOM access, using a Javascript array/object should be faster in that case.

It's up to you really.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. It's perfectly valid to store data associated with HTML attributes in this way. MDN has a whole article about it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes The question I would be asking is does this fit with how your consuming / interacting with that data. Are you using a javascript framework? Have you considered loading this data in from an external source as JSON? Would that be a better fit? In my case I would tend to load this data in from an external json feed. I find that more flexable and it suits libraries like angular.

Comment: In my case, i need to know which rock is clicked and get all its properties. If it dont put all properties on dom, i will put a data-id on dom, then use this id to search some data structure(eg. JSON) in javascript and get all properties.